# Grails Quartz Plugin concurrent not working

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I'm having trouble getting my Quartz Job in Grails to run concurrently as expected. Here is what my job looks like. I've commented out the lines that use the Executor plugin but when I don't comment them out, my code works as expected.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder

class PollerJob {

    def concurrent = true
    def myService1
    def myService2
    //def executorService

    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'pollerTrigger', startDelay:0, cronExpression: ConfigurationHolder.config.poller.cronExpression
    }

    def execute() {
        def config = ConfigurationHolder.config
        //Session session = null;
        if (config.runPoller == true) {
            //def result = executorService.submit({
                myService1.doStuff()
                myService2.doOtherStuff()
            //} as Callable)
        }
    }

}
```

In my case, the myService2.doOtherStuff() is taking a very long time to complete which overlaps the next time this job should trigger. I don't mind if they overlap which is why I explicitly added def concurrent = true but it isn't working.

I have version 0.4.2 of the Quartz plugin and Grails 1.3.7. Am I doing something wrong here? Seems like a pretty straightforward feature to use. I'm not opposed to using the Executor plugin but it seems like I shouldn't have to.

I'm not sure it matters but the cronExpression I'm loading from config in this case is meant to execute this job every minute: "0 * * * * ?"

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there was a hidden config that I was not aware of that was keeping this from working. In my conf folder there was a file called quartz.properties which contained the following property:

org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1

After increasing this number, my job was triggering even when it had not finished the previous execution.